# How to override Dropbox's online file list with my local file list?

Tags: fedora, dropbox

Several months ago, I was using Dropbox while using Fedora as my primary OS. Then, my Internet connection was disconnected for a period of several months. In the meanwhile, I reorganized my Dropbox contents i.e. moved the contents around for better organization and also removed Fedora to install Windows 7. However, now that I have Internet access and hence install Dropbox again, it appears that Dropbox is forcing me to download the old file list from the cloud, and download several files that I deleted during the time when I had no Internet access. So, how do I override the filelist on the cloud with the file list on my laptop at present?

Comment: so the latest version has the organization you don't want. But does dropbox perhaps offer a slightly older than latest version, that is from when you reorganized it? in which case you could download that and replace the one you have in your computer, then let dropbox take it back off your computer.

Comment: You may just want to move/copy the files somewhere else, let Dropbox "update" the folder, then replace it all with the files you want.

Comment: @barlop Uh, I don't believe that you're quite clear on my situation. I did the reorganization after my Internet went out. So, the copy on the Dropbox servers is the unorganized one.

Comment: @user319810 yes I understand that.but what i'm saying is,doesn't dropbox ALSO have an archive of all ur files/folders from before you did the reorganization.One reads that "By default, Dropbox saves a history of all deleted n earlier versions of files for 30 days"So let's say  you had the Internet up to the middle of the 2nd of april.During the 2nd of april u lost Internet access.u reorganized things on dropbox on the 10th April.Dropbox had that.Then you got net access on the 13th.Sadly Dropbox got that.But maybe dropbox ALSO has a copy of how all your files were from the 10/11/12th Apr

Comment: Why not log onto dropbox.com and delete the unorganized files, then install Dropbox and copy paste the organized files into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, you basically have to start from scratch.

I would move the files out of your Dropbox folder, then go to dropbox.com and delete all the files. Let the system sync and then copy your files back in.

I suspect that you probably set up Dropbox and told it that the location was your Dropbox folder rather than installing Dropbox clean and then copying the files in. I think that in a dispute Dropbox shows you it's before you show it yours so it will download all the files it has, then upload new ones from your system.

I don't know what the policy is if there is a file dispute, whether it's last modified or Dropbox becomes the source. I haven't had it happen yet.